# Attach click event to span tag in HTML?

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` that contains many `spans` and each of those `span`s contains a single `href`.

How do I attach a click event to the `a` tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `live` selector would be `div span a` (an `a` somewhere inside a `span` that's somewhere inside a `div`). E.g.:

```
$('div span a').live('click', function() {
  // ...
});
```

If you want to limit it to *only* an `a` that's a *direct child* of a `span` which is a *direct child* of a `div`, that would be `div > span > a` (or `div span > a` for `a`s that are direct children of `span`s anywhere in a `div`, etc.).

If you want to do this for just one specific div, replace `div` above with `#the_id_of_the_div` (or any other selector that will identify that specific div).

Answer (score 5):

If there is a large number of anchors (`a`, or "hrefs" as the OP calls them) then this might be better to write using event delegation: attach a single `click` listener to the parent `div` and in the callback, find out which `a` originally fired the event.

```
$('#yourDiv').click(function (event)
{
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if($target.is('div>span>a')
    {
        // your callback logic here, where you can consider
        // $target to be analogous to $(this) in a non-delegated handler
    }
});
```

Comment: ++ wow, very nice way to handle that! but i think his problem is the preventDefault(), don't you?

Comment: This is what the `.live` and `.delegate` methods do internally, no reason to implement it manually.